# Angular 8: Reset form inputs values to another value

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, angular-forms

It's possible to reset form inputs value and subsequently set another value from a service? 
I want to save old value in `saveService`, reset `service` and set `name` attribute of service to *Hello World!*

So in my saveService i correctly have the old value, but the input in my form remains empty.
I've tried also without form reset but nothing.

This is my code:

> **.html**
>
> ```
> <form id="formExample">
>     <input type="text" id="name" [(ngModel)]="service.name" #name>
> </form> 
> <button (click)="save()">save</button> 
> <button (click)="reset()">reset</button>
> ```
>
> **.ts**
>
> ```
> export class Hero {
>     constructor(public service: Service, public saveService: SaveService){}
>     save(){
>         this.saveService.name = this.service.name
>     }
>     reset(){
>         this.service = new Service();
>         let form = document.getElementsById('formExample');
>
>         form.reset();
>
>         this.service.name = 'Hello World!';
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: please post a minimal reproduction on stackblitz so that we can help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ngModel` is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
control must be defined as `'standalone'` in `ngModelOptions`.

```
<form id="formExample" #myForm>
    <input [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text" id="name" [(ngModel)]="service.name" #name>
</form> 
<button (click)="save()">save</button> 
<button (click)="reset(myForm)">reset</button>
```

```
export class Hero {
    constructor(public service: Service, public saveService: SaveService){}
    save(){
        this.saveService.name = this.service.name
    }
    reset(form){
        this.service = new Service();

        form.reset();

        this.service.name = 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG Thanks! I didn't even noticed it